# Adding a cert to HTTPS request

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate

Our iPhone app communicates JSON with the server using AFNetworking and previously, we ignored the invalid certification error by setting

```
#define AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ = 1;
```

however after a while, the server became ready and we have a cert for the connection.

How can I add the cert to the request? We want to remove _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ soon as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is the client presenting a certificate to the server, or are you trying to allow the client to accept a particular (non validated) certificate that the server presents?

Comment: The client is presenting a certificate to the server. But I am not sure how to present it.